# Não compila, erro: use of deleted function

Tags: c++, sfml

Tenho um projeto simples no **codeblocks** (windows), estou usando a biblioteca **SFML**, ao tentar chamar um método que criei onde passo a window e um objeto qualquer, no ato de compilar recebo o seguinte erro:

> error: use of deleted function 'sf::Window::Window(const sf::Window&)'

Uso os seguintes includes:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

Função que criei:

```
bool LimitaMovimento(sf::RenderWindow window,sf::Sprite img){
    if(img.getPosition().x >= window.getPosition().x){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Call dela no método `main`:

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
        if(LimitaMovimento(window,img)){
              img.move(-5,0);
        }
        cout << window.getPosition().x <<endl;
}
```

*obs o objeto **window** já foi instanciado obviamente, sem a call do `LimitaMovimento`, funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de passar a window por referência.

```
bool LimitaMovimento(sf::RenderWindow& window,sf::Sprite img){
    if(img.getPosition().x >= window.getPosition().x){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.